# Servicestack security over mvc on n-tier layer application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, c#-4.0, servicestack

One of the biggest disadvantages of .net security is that the security annotations does not live outside of the mvc controller.

`CustomerController` calls `CustomerService` calls `CustomerRepository`

each of the above are in a different dll.
I want to secure `CustomerService` with annotations and not `CustomerController`.

1. Is it possible to do on servicestack? is it good practice?
2. Is there any example of n-tier architecture example with servicestack?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to do on servicestack? is it good practice?**
Within ServiceStack [you can apply authentication/authorization attributes at different levels](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#enabling-authentication-at-different-levels) (Request Dto, Service Action, Service class or a Serivce's base class) . You can also create [Filter Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) as well.

**Is there any example of n-tier architecture example with servicestack?**
[This is not so much an example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure) but the structure of a typical layout of a ServiceStack project.